# change Vertical stacked bar to horizontal stacked Bar d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Hi everyone I am working with d3 and stacked bar, I have my stacked Bar in vertical version (works fine), and I want to convert in horizontal bar...

my vertical function do this..

```
  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.3);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var dataIntermediate = options.map(function(item){
      return datos.map(function(d){
        if (item in d)
          return {x:d.label, y:d[item]};
        else
          return{x:d.label, y:0};
      });
    });

    var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

    x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function (d) {
      return d.x; 
    }));

    y.domain([0,
        d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
            function (d) { 
              return d.y0 + d.y;
            })
        ])
      .nice();

    var layer = svg.selectAll(".stack")
      .data(dataStackLayout)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "stack")
      .style("fill", function (d, i) {
          return color(i);
      });

    layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function (d) {return d; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function (d) { 
        return x(d.x); 
      })
      .attr("y", function (d) { 
        return y(d.y + d.y0); 
      })
      .attr("height", function (d) { 
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0); 
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .on("mousemove", function(d){
        div.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px");
        div.style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px");
        div.style("display", "inline-block");
        div.html((d.x)+"<br>"+"Code"+": "+(d.code)+"<br>"+"Value"+": "+(d.y));
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d){
        div.style("display", "none");
      });
```

in my horizontal version, I change I change all my `x` for `y` and my `x0` for `y0` and vise verse  and change my scale too

```
  var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], 0.35);

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);
```

But don't work... any idea

Comment: Hard to say without a reproductible example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea I think, swapping x for y (and modifying the scales as you noted), but there are probably a few other steps, such as a couple key changes for width and height.

One quick note is that the y coordinates start from `height` and work their way up (to zero). With x coordinates, you start at zero and work your way out (to `width`). So if you just swap x for y, you will get a horizontal bar chart that starts on the right (which may be desirable).

More importantly, in your example:

```
  .attr("y", function (d) { 
    return y(d.y + d.y0); 
  })
  .attr("height", function (d) { 
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0); 
  })
```

The starting y attribute looks good, but the height attribute should not be dependent on the data values, it should be equal to y.bandwidth().

Likewise for x:

```
.attr("x", function (d) { 
    return x(d.x); 
 })
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
```

The width of each part of the horizontal stacked bar should be dependent on data values. This can be solved by swapping the attr "height" for "width" and vice versa.

I've built a comparison on bl.ocks.org between the two orientations (it's a horizontal bar chart based on one of Mike Bostock's blocks, but with comments showing the original content of each line). It can be found here: https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/0aedd5f3fb8b099e3e10690bd38bd458